# Angularjs ui bootstrap - put html inside popover

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using official [angular bootstrap directives](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/popover) .

I want to use of of it's popovers .

In the documentation it says that if you want to insert html inside the popover you should use **popover-html**, like bellow :

```
     <button popover-html="{{getTag()}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dynamic Popover</button>
     <button popover-html="<a>Just fucin show me !</a>" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Click me </button>
```

But this will raise the following console error :

> Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression at column 1 of the expression [sdfsdfsdf] starting at [sdfsdfsdf].
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%3C&p1=not%20a%20primary%20expression&p2=1&p3=%3Ca%3Esdfsdfsdf%3C%2Fa%3E&p4=%3Ca%3Esdfsdfsdf%3C%2Fa%3E

You can see the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Z5HHXSN2VFXmQCe6i5nk?p=preview)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the brackets and the `$compile` function:

HTML:

```
<button popover-html="getTag()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Dynamic Popover</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.getTag = function(){
   return '<a>sdfsdfsdf</a>';
}
```