# angular-ui: Using popover-template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui, popover

I posted an earlier question: [angular-ui-bootstrap: Implementing html in popover using popover-html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911537/angular-ui-bootstrap-implementing-html-in-popover-using-popover-html?noredirect=1#comment53652304_32911537) and it was suggested I use popover-template.

```
<i popover-template="popover-partial.html" popover-title="In Progress" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="popover-partial.html">
    <b>Jody</b>
</script>
```

So I'm trying to do that but now the popover won't activate on click.

I'm using version 0.13.4.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`popover-template` value should be `string`, In other way you could say that, it needs an `expression`/`scopeVariable`.

```
<i popover-template="'popover-partial.html'" 
  popover-title="In Progress" 
  class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign">
</i>
```

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FWvSiXiW2S8M7fd9Jxo0?p=preview)

Comment: I just changed to `<i popover-template="'popover-partial.html'" popover-title="In Progress" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>` and it still doesn't activate on click.

Answer (score 4):

You have to expose the template to the scope for it to work. This is better anyways as now your template can be more dynamic by setting variables and models on the scope. You can also set up a template provider so you don't have all of these little script tags under your html code.

In your view:

```
<i popover-template="popover.templateUrl" 
popover-title="popover.title" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="popover-partial.html">
<b>Jody</b>
</script>
```

In your controller:

```
$scope.popover = {
templateUrl: 'popover-partial.html',
title: 'Title'
};
```